# Minimal projections of a von-Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional von-Neumann algebra. We know this algebra is generated by its projections. My question maybe simple. Can one computing these projections? What about its minimal or central projections?

If possible please give me a reference for this.

Thanks

Comment: I’m not familiar with the assumptions for this field. Isn’t there identity, and doesn’t finite dimensionality mean this is a finite product of matrix ring over the complex numbers? I would think that answers all your questions..

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define "compute". To "compute" an element of an algebra (or any other mathematical object, for that matter) you need to have some kind of presentation of the object.

In the case of a finite-dimensional von Neumann/C$^*$-algebra, one can prove that they are always (isomorphic to) a direct sum of full matrix algebras. Are you starting with the former or the latter?

And again with the word "compute". Can you compute all rank-2 orthogonal projections in $M_3(\mathbb C)$? It depends on what you mean. They are all of the form $vv^*+ww^*$ with $v,w$ unit mutually orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb C^3$, so in a sense they are very explicit. On the other hand, I'm not saying what $v$ and $w$ are. If you try to somehow parametrize them, it can probably be done, but it is not pretty and the general expression for $vv^*+ww^*$ will be headache that likely contributes nothing.

Anyway, I haven't really answered your question. It depends on how you express your algebra, and what you mean by "compute".

Comment: Dear prof, Thanks for your attention. Infact I need to know the dimension of my finite dimensional von-Neumann. As I know, the dimension of $M$ equals to the number of minimal projections in $M$. How can I find the dimension of $M$?

Comment: Also $M$ is a subalgebra of $B(H)$.

Comment: That's true only for commutative $M$. The number of minimal projections is always infinite whenever the algebra is non-commutative. The dimension of a finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra is $\sum_{k=1}^m n_k^2$ where $m$ is the number of minimal central projections and $n_k$ is the trace (or rank) of the corresponding minimal central projection.

Comment: As for "finding the dimension of $M$" you can't unless you know what $M$ is.

Comment: would you introduce me a reference?

Comment: I'm not particularly aware. There is section 9.3 in Kadison-Ringrose, for instance. But it is probably hard to read without some background in von Neumann algebras. And, as soon as you know a bit of von Neumann algebra theory, deducing the structure for finite-dimensional algebras becomes an easy exercise.

Answer (score 0):

By the structure theorem of finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras (see, Takesaki's, Theory of Operator Algebras, Theorem 11.2), $M\cong\bigoplus_{r=1}^N M_{n_r}(\mathbb{C})$ for some unique $n_1,\dots,n_N\in\mathbb{N}^+$.  Let $e_{ij}^{(r)}\in M_{n_r}(\mathbb{C})$ be the matrix with the $ij$-th entry equal to 1 and the rest of the entries vanishing. Then a maximal family of minimal projections are $e_{ii}^{(r)}$ for all $r\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ and $i\in\{1,\dots,n_r\}$. The central projections are of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n_r}e_{ii}^{(r)}$ for all $r\in\{1,\dots,N\}$.